# Javascript running in wrong tab

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am very new to JavaScript (started yesterday) and currently trying to write a Tampermonkey userscript to integrate Youtube Converter on the youtube.com/watch page, but i am facing a weird problem.

The main structure is that i have a userscript for youtube.com/watch that adds a button under the video lining to youtube converter with a fitting query string. Then I have a userscript for youtube converter that clicks the download button as soon as it is ready.

It works, but it works too much and in the wrong place...

The problem is that the script for adding the button starts running in the Youtube Converter tab and the script for clicking the download button starts in the Youtube Converter tab and then halfway through switches to the Youtube tab for some reason.

The button insertion script is run once in 5 seconds because site switching works weirdly on youtube and it doesnt retrigger Tampermonkey.

Here is the onclick for the added button under the Youtube Video:

```
function convertViaYoutubeconverter(){
var ytURL = window.location.href;
window.open("http://www.yt-mp3.com/watch?v="+ytURL.split("=")[1], '_blank');}
```

And here is the download "clickbot":

```
alert("Where am I");
if(!document.getElementsByClassName("btn-dl download disabled")[0])
{
    window.open(document.getElementsByClassName("btn-dl download")[0].getAttribute("href"),"_blank");
    alert("Downloading");
}
```

Where it alerts "Where am I" in the Youtube Converter tab but proceeds to throw errors of being unable to read the property "getAttribute" of null in the Youtube tab, where it references the clickbot script.

As requested here are the Headers of my userscripts:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YoutubeConverter Autodownload
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://www.yt-mp3.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
```

And

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YoutubeConverter in Youtube
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
```

I dont know where the problem lies, if it is my code, Chrome, or Tampermonkey, but I think stackoverflow will be able to help anyway. Thanks in advance

Comment: make sure that there is a element with the classes : `btn-dl` and `download`

Comment: if it'r running in the wrong place then your include urls must be wrong. post the header part of your userscripts..

Comment: @KevinKloet Its an Element of class btn-dl, download and disabled until its ready, from there on its of classes btn-dl and download

Comment: Are you sure the button is there when you select it?